# Is a measure on a circle completely determined by its "contours"?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $v$ be a measure on a circle ($S^1$) with $v(S^1)=1$. Let $H_v$ be the set of intervals $I\subseteq S^1$ such that $v(I)=1/2$.
Is $v$ completely determined by $H_v$?
That is: if two measures $u,v$ have $H_u=H_v$, does it imply that $u=v$?

NOTE: For my application, the following assumptions can be made; I do not know if they are required:

- All measures are absolutely continuous with respect to length;
- All measures are strictly positive: $v(I)>0$ for every $I$ with a positive length.

Comment: No, it's not true.  Let $\theta_0$ be the angle at which $\mu([0,\theta_0])=1/2$.  You can completely reassign $\mu$ on the interval $[0,\theta_0]$ to another positive measure of total weight $1/2$, and then reprogram $\mu$ on the remaining interval $[\theta_0, 2\pi]$ so as to keep the set of intervals $H_\mu$ the same.  If you can't figure out yourself how to do the reprogramming I'll write a complete solution (or at least figure out where if I'm wrong about this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple counterexample.  The function
$$\cos^2\theta = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2\theta))$$
is $\pi$-periodic and
$$\int_{0}^\pi \cos^2\theta \,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
so if you take
$$d\mu=\frac{1}{\pi}\cos^2\theta \,d\theta$$
then
$$\int_{T}^{T+\pi} d\mu = \frac{1}{2}$$
for all $T\in\Bbb{R}$.  So $d\mu$ has the same $H_\mu$ as the measure $\frac{1}{2\pi}dx$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: I did not understand how exactly you defined $\mu$. Should there be an integral sign there?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: $\mu([\theta_1,\theta_2])=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \cos^2 \theta\,d\theta$ for $\theta_1,\theta_2\in[0,2\pi]$.  I corrected the text it should've been $d\mu$ instead of $\mu$.